# Не получается решить проблему с плавающей точкой

Tags: javascript

Не получается решить проблему с плавающей точкой (Делал и `toFixed` и `Math.floor` ничего не помогает.

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      result: '',
      numbers: ['*', '/', '-', 9, 8, 7, '+', 6, 5, 4, '%', 3, 2, 1, 0, '.'],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    displayItem: function (number) {
      this.result += number;
    },
    clear: function () {
      this.result = '';
    },
     calc: function () {
        this.result = eval(this.result.toFixed());
    },
  },
}).mount('#app');
```

```css
.calculator {
   margin: 100px auto;
   max-width: 300px;
   background-color: #233446;
   color: #fff;
   padding: 15px;
   box-shadow: 5px black;
   user-select: none;
}

.wrapper-item{
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
   grid-gap: 10px;
}

.item{
   grid-column: 25%;
   padding: 15px;
   color: #fff;
   font-size: 26px;
   border: none;
   background-color: #31455e;
   cursor: pointer;
}

.item:hover{
   background-color: #40b785;
}

.input{
   grid-column: 1/ -1;
   height: 50px;
   background-color: #31455e;
   text-align: right;
   outline: none;
   font-size: 26px;
   color: #fff;
}

::placeholder{
   font-size: 26px;
   color: #fff;
   padding-right: 5px;
}

.equally{
   grid-column: 2/-1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>calculator</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

   <div id='app'>
      <div class="calculator">
         <div class="wrapper-item">
            <input class="input" name="input" type="text" placeholder="0" readonly v-model='result'>
            <button class="item" @click="clear()">C</button>
            <button class="item" v-for="num of numbers" @click="displayItem(num)">{{num}}</button>
            <button class="item equally" @click="calc()">=</button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>


   <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
   <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Это как прийти к доктору и сказать: у меня болит. А что болит, где болит, в какой-то конкретный период и время болит - типа тыжврач, должен сразу распознать по интонации, да?

Comment: А, что не понятного? Описал же. При любой операции с дробями к примеру 0.1 + 0.2 = 0.3000000004 , и метод toFixed не убирает ее

Comment: Где написано про  0.1 + 0.2 = 0.3000000004? Ткни в место в вопросе

Comment: А, по логике разве не понятно, где может быть плавающая точка в калькуляторе с точкой?))))))))

Comment: Причём тут плавающая точка в калькуляторе и абстрактная проблема с плавающей точкой? Я тебе могу десяток проблем написать.

Comment: В каком месте она абстрактная?) Ладно, иди попей чаю и успокойся)

Comment: "Не получается решить проблему с плавающей точкой" --- о какой из десятков проблем тут говорится?

Comment: В калькуляторе только одна точка))))

Comment: Как связан какой-то там калькулятор и проблема с плавающей точкой в двоичной арифметике?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    this.result = eval(this.result).toFixed(6);
```

Comment: Благодарю!) За помощь!)

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]